# Sefer on Conversion in Halacha

Tags: product-recommendation, conversion-to-judaism

I am looking for a sefer in either english or hebrew that provides a comprehensive discussion on the halachos of conversion. I'm specifically looking for how it has evolved throughout history and the broad range of opinions relating to it.

I would love recommendations of books from all sections of the Jewish community.

Thanks

Comment: good person on this sbject @yehoshualevy

Comment: זרע ישראל .....

Answer (score 4):

Menachem Finkelstein's excellent *Conversion: Halakhah and Practice* is available in English and Hebrew. It covers the topic from biblical sources through to 20th-century responsa.

Answer (score 3):

[Laws of Conversion](https://www.israelbookshop.com/laws-of-gerut-conversion-to-judaism-author-by-rabbi-rafael-cohen-soae.html) by Rabbi Rafael Cohen Soae provides a comprehensive treatment on the laws as they are currently upheld, and a short summary of differences between different communities and countries, as well as a short summary of how things were done when we still went by the Shulchan Arch for conversion.

The book is available in either bilingual English-Hebrew or Spanish-Hebrew format.

Answer (score 0):

Shulchan Arukh - Yore Deah, Siman 268

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Does this siman cover "a comprehensive discussion on the halachos of conversion and specifically how they have evolved throughout history and the broad range of opinions relating to it." ?

Comment: @mbloch evolution of discussion could happen, but still it's not supposed to go far away from Halacha standards, and Shulchan Arukh is widely accepted and by Ashkenazim and by Sephardim

Comment: That is all right but the goal of this site is to answer people's questions. As such your question doesn't address the original question.

Comment: @mbloch I don't understand. Question was to provide a source for "comprehensive discussion on the halachos of conversion". "specifically looking for how it has evolved throughout history". First point - Torah, second point probably Yevamot, third Shulchan Aruch Siman 268 where Joseph Caro discussed and got approved all aspects with rabbis from both sides and made comprehensive work that is there. Clear Halacha. What kind of other books are you referring? Are we discussing Judaism and applied Halacha or opinion journalism?

Comment: SA as we know is a digest, maybe if you had referred to the Beit Yosef and commentaries, it might have been an answer. If you look at the other two answers, you have a first sense of the answers likely expected by the original questioner. Also if you have sources on conversion in Yevamot